# On an open interval prove that if $f$ is differentiable and |f'(x)| \leq C then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding how to work this out, been working on it for hours to no avail...This is a question in my homework:

Statement of the problem: suppose that E is an open interval. Prove that if $f$ is differentiable on E and $|f'(x)| \leq C$ for all $x \in E$ then $f$ has property $X(c)$ (the property is Lipschitz continuous)

Comment: (Assuming that $f$ is real-valued) this is exactly the sort of thing you use the Mean Value Theorem for...

Comment: Hint: the mean value theorem states that if $f : A\to\mathbb R$ ($A\subseteq\mathbb R$) is continuous on the closed interval $[x_1, x_2]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(x_1,x_2)$, then there exists $c\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_1)-f(x_2)=f'(c)(x_1-x_2)$.

Answer (score 3):

This follows straight away from the Mean Value Theorem. Indeed, let $x,y\in E$. Then $$ f(x)-f(y) = f'(c)(x-y) $$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$ (even in the case $x=y$). And now $$ |f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(c)||x-y| \leq C|x-y|, $$ which is the desired Lipschitz continuity.